# Convert UTF16 to Windows 1250

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

I have a file, which I open with `FileStream` and I modify the text. The standard encoding of this is UTF16. After this, I would like to upload the modified file somewhere, but that has to be in a Windows-1250 format.

How is it possible to convert UTF16 to Windows-1250 encoding?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `TEncoding` to encode your string in a specific encoding.

```
var
  Ansi1250Enc: TEncoding;
....
Ansi1250Enc := TEncoding.GetEncoding(1250);
```

Then you can use `GetBytes` to encode a string as a byte array:

```
var
  EncodedBytes: TBytes;
  str: string;
....
str := ...; // get your text into a string variable by whatever means
EncodedBytes := Ansi1250Enc.GetBytes(str);
```

Or if you have the text stored in a string list you can save it like so:

```
Strings.SaveToFile(FileName, Ansi1250Enc);
```

Don't forget to destroy the `Ansi1250Enc` when you are done with it.

Comment: That's nice! Thank you very much!

Comment: Omg, get a room!   ;)